# How to insert a new paragraph in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using a script that replace strings in a Google Docs template. If I use the `\n` command, I can get a new line in the template.

```
sample = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
```

I get something like this:

```
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

But I'd like to add not a new string, but a new paragraph (according to the template settings):

```
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

There's some way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create paragraph from within the paragraph's content, use the [appendParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) method in your script by slicing your string in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    sample = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
 </p><p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>"
```

This will work if you have the string part you want to have paragraph. If not, you can replace `/n` with `</p><p>` in the string

Comment: This not HTML...please reconsider you answer.

Comment: This is about displaying paragraphs ans HTML is one of the ways.

Comment: This is all happening in a Google document. Google documents don't use HTML but plain text in their content... that's why there is a   /n used to break the line and not <br> in the original post.

Comment: Not a pretty way but you can change /n s to <br/> with Jquery maybe.